# MySQL select different running number (missing number) of column?

Tags: mysql, select, myisam

#### [my example table]

```
[user_table]
+------------------------------------------+
|   id   |   ref_id  |   name   |   ....   |
+------------------------------------------+
|   1    |     0     |   John   |   ....   |
|   2    |     1     |   James  |   ....   |
|   3    |     2     |   Jinny  |   ....   |
|   4    |     3     |   Jose   |   ....   |
|   5    |     4     |   Joe    |   ....   |
|   6    |     5     |   Joy    |   ....   |
|   7    |     8     |   Joey   |   ....   |
|   8    |     11    |   Jimmy  |   ....   |
|   9    |     12    |   Jacky  |   ....   |
|   10   |     13    |   Jung   |   ....   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

above is a simple data i want to get missing numbers in column `ref_id` so, lose number is `6, 7, 9 and 10`

I want to MySQL some query code for get it.

#### [expect result]

```
+------------+
|   result   |
+------------+
|     6      |
|     7      |
|     9      |
|     10     |
+------------+
```

Comment: 'i want to get different of number in column ref_id' - different of what? AND why aren't 7 thru 10 different.

Comment: How do we know to stop at 13?

Comment: Do you have table with all `ref_id`? I guess it references some other table.

Comment: What version of MySql do you use?

Comment: @Strawberry : real data is stop at 10 million records

Comment: @MichałTurczyn : yes i have

Comment: @MichałTurczyn : version 5.6

Comment: OK. How do we know to stop at 10 million?

Comment: @bombkiml If someone's answer solved your problem, you might want to accept it as the answer using the big checkbox. Otherwise write how you solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table, called `numbers`, with all possible numbers.
2. Do `SELECT ... FROM numbers LEFT JOIN your_table ON ... WHERE ... IS NULL` to find the missing rows

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with `LEFT JOIN` on the same table and `SELECT` only the pairs with the second `NULL` value.

```
SELECT u1.id as result
FROM user_table u1
LEFT JOIN user_table u2 ON u1.id = u2.ref_id
WHERE u2.id IS NULL
```

**Update**:

You can test [HERE](https://sqltest.net/#617459).

My solution works in both case.